# Not able to update Subscriber Status using Ampscript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I am trying to update Subscriber status using following Ampscript code. Can someone please assist on what could be wrong with the code. It gives following error message -

> Error Message:    Update or insert of view or function
>   'C7229040._subscribers' failed because it contains a derived or
>   constant field.

Code :

```
UpdateData("_subscribers",1,"EmailAddress",@name,"Status","Active")
```

Thanks

Answer (score 10):

you can not use `DataView` to update the subscriber status. you should use [API AmpScript functions](https://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/api_ampscript_functions/) and below is the sample code for your reference.

```
%%[
SET @Subscriber = CreateObject("Subscriber")
SetObjectProperty(@Subscriber, "SubscriberKey","test@gmail.com")
SetObjectProperty(@Subscriber, "EmailAddress", "test@gmail.com")
SetObjectProperty(@Subscriber, "Status", "Active" )
SET @Status = InvokeUpdate(@Subscriber, @createErrDesc, @createErrNo, @createOpts)
]%%

%%=v(@Status)=%%
```

Answer (score 2):

The following lines work for me. The `@Unsub_All` variable either took the value of "Active" or "Unsubscribed".

Note: This code is on a landing page belonging to a business unit of the SFMC instance.

```
%%[

/*Update the unsubscribe from all list*/  
SET @ll_sub = CreateObject("Subscriber")

SetObjectProperty(@ll_sub,"EmailAddress", @SubscriberKey)
SetObjectProperty(@ll_sub,"SubscriberKey", @SubscriberKey)

SET @client = CreateObject("ClientID")
SetObjectProperty(@client, "ID", @memberID)
SetObjectProperty(@client, "IDSpecified", "true")
SetObjectProperty(@ll_sub, "Client", @client)

SetObjectProperty(@ll_sub,"Status", @Unsub_All)
Set @options = CreateObject("UpdateOptions")
Set @save = CreateObject("SaveOption")
SetObjectProperty(@save,"SaveAction","UpdateAdd")
SetObjectProperty(@save,"PropertyName","Status")
AddObjectArrayItem(@options,"SaveOptions", @save)

/* Here is where we actually update the Subscriber object */
Set @update_sub = InvokeUpdate(@ll_sub, @update_sub_status, @update_sub_errorcode, @options)

]%%
```